# How to show important notice when there is no space left?

Tags: user-behavior, info-visualisation

I'm in a situation where the whole mobile screen is already occupied with the needed UI components.

I would like to show a important notice to the user.Where should it go?
The notice may cover the points like:

- Your query may take upto 7 days
- This is done via ...
- The response is guaranteed and ..

Just 3-4 points at the maximum.Where is the best place to show them as it's necessary for the user to notice them.

Also, should the message be displayed only once or every time?

I have no experience at UX.

Comment: Do they have to stay on screen? Can you post a screenshot / wireframe?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since it's more of an information - depending upon its importance to your users, you could either -

1) Slide it, from bottom/top as an alert/messaging bar. Check this [example](https://www.google.co.in/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fg.twimg.com%2Fblog%2Fblog%2Fimage%2Fip5_alert_screenshot_0.png&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fblog.twitter.com%2F2013%2Ftwitter-alerts-new-countries-and-features&docid=kkgC-ogcQbBYHM&tbnid=9HNf69j_8TaDUM%3A&vet=10ahUKEwilobWyzIfTAhUWTo8KHddRB1QQMwgaKAEwAQ..i&w=450&h=818&safe=active&bih=759&biw=1440&q=mobile%20app%20alerts%20bottom&ved=0ahUKEwilobWyzIfTAhUWTo8KHddRB1QQMwgaKAEwAQ&iact=mrc&uact=8#h=818&imgrc=9HNf69j_8TaDUM:&vet=10ahUKEwilobWyzIfTAhUWTo8KHddRB1QQMwgaKAEwAQ..i&w=450).

2) If its significantly important, you could also use a modal pop-up.
[Example](https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/564x/fe/66/a2/fe66a20de7cc838d44fdbb22a1856c79.jpg).

The above holds true, if this message needs to be shown upon some action.
However, if you need to show it as a default part of the app information, then try to show it in the intro, say in the onboarding of the app. [Example](http://media02.hongkiat.com/mobile-onboarding-screen-designs/15-onboarding-screen-mobile-app-designs.jpg).